# Check if correct number of links appear with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm re-writing tests from Test Unit into Rspec/capybara and I'm just trying to figure out the correct syntax. I want to hit the root_path and check that there is exactly one links to '/' (in the header).

The relevant part of the old test was:

```
test 'layout links' do
  get root_path
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', root_path, count: 1
end
```

I can test for the existence of the link with Rspec using:

```
it 'should have correct number of links' do
  visit root_path
  expect(page).to have_link('Site Name', root_path)
end
```

and I tried adding

```
expect(page).to have_link('Site Name', root_path, count: 1)
```

but it will only take 0..2 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass path via `href` option:

```
expect(page).to have_link('Site Name', href: root_path, count: 1)
```